# How to remove space between ul and div in css

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with unwanted gap between `ul` and `div`. Maybe you know solution?

```css
#tabs {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
}

#tabs li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 .5em 0 0;
}

#tabs a {
  position: relative;
  background: #ddd;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff, #ddd);
  padding: .7em 3.5em;
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  font-size: 16px;
}

#content {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 2em;
  height: 220px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 -2px 3px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  width: 1100px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul id="tabs">
  <li><a href="#" name="tab1">First</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" name="tab2">Second</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" name="tab3">Random</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="content">
  <div id="tab1">...</div>
  <div id="tab2">...</div>
  <div id="tab3">...</div>
</div>
```

This problem occurred after inline-block adding. I searched for solutions, but what I have found that was for horizontal gaps (I have fixed it by adding `font-size: 0;` in parent tab). Maybe there is some solution for vertical gaps?

Comment: You would be best off using `flexbox` or `float:left` as inline element tend to naturally have gaps in them

Comment: Please create a fiddle

Comment: I don't see any gaps? https://jsfiddle.net/vy6ptnmj/36/ could you elaborate more?

Comment: * {margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box}

Comment: @VXp That will remove padding from the elements that's required as well.

Comment: @Djave I can't float:left it would break my centering.

Comment: @Mantas See the solution.

Comment: You could remove the `font-size: 0;` and just use `margin-bottom: -5px;`.

Comment: The bottom margin is because of the padding put on content -.- , see the solution. Updated a border to show that.

Comment: @uom-pgregorio I can't remove font-size: 0 , because of inline-block bug for horizontal gaps between tabs.

Comment: @uom-pgregorio, Thank you I puted font-size: 0 to #tabs a and used margin-bottom: -5px; at parent. That worked!!!

Comment: If you need to fix the space between the `inline-block` elements you could follow this guide and you won't have to use `font-size: 0;` https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/#article-header-id-0

Comment: @uom-pgregorio I used one of this site tricks. Font change gave me better result than other tips.

Comment: @uom-pgregorio when I am using this margin-bottom, my z-index isn't working. Maybe you know why?

Comment: @Highdef I know but that can be adjusted later, just an easy and quick way to see if the problem gets solved.

Comment: `z-index` should still work and shouldn't really be affected by a negative margin. Could you create a fiddle showing the problem with the z-index?

Answer (score 1):

in #content add float:left; margin-top:0;

Comment: Please use _anything_ better than `float` Flexbox is a *much* better solution.

Comment: It would depend on what browser compatibility is required. For example, does it needs to work on Internet Explorer?

Comment: If I still had to support IE before 11 I would cry for several weeks and then refuse to see any friends, stop shaving and wear a loin cloth while living in a frozen cave. Then I would get back to work and still refuse to use `float`. I would use `position: absolute` if I had no other options. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the font-size:0

and edit margin to this

```
#tabs li {

    margin: 0 0;

    }
```

you gave it 0.5em which is causing the space between them

Hope it helps

Comment: "unwanted gap between ul and div."

Comment: He set the margin to `0 .5em 0 0` which is just the right margin. OP is talking about the bottom margin.

Answer (score 0):

You added padding to the content div which caused this effect

Here's a fiddle where I changed the padding to 0 2em instead

https://jsfiddle.net/6r0x3n0e/

```
#content {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 2em;
  height: 220px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 -2px 3px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  width: 1100px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Set padding to the following: padding:0em 2em 2em 2em;

```css
#tabs {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
}

#tabs li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 .5em 0 0;
}

#tabs a {
  position: relative;
  background: #ddd;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff, #ddd);
  padding: .7em 3.5em;
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  font-size: 16px;
}

#content {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0em 2em 2em 2em;
  height: 220px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 -2px 3px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  width: 1100px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul id="tabs">
  <li><a href="#" name="tab1">First</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" name="tab2">Second</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" name="tab3">Random</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="content">
  <div id="tab1">...</div>
  <div id="tab2">...</div>
  <div id="tab3">...</div>
</div>
```